# How to read the log file

Tags: java

I have a log file, i want to read the data from the log file which shows how many requests are there, the code must be in such a way that there should be an 5 min starts mapped to a console.

Someone please help me.

Comment: And adding to above, wat you mean by 'give me the code..'?

Answer (score 1):

Use `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader in
   = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.log"));
```

Comment: But BufferedReader is throws an exception in jframe.

Comment: @Naresh - Of course!  you need to wrap your code in try..catch block.